# How to Create a half circle progress bar in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, progress-bar

I want to implement a design like the image in Flutter. But I am stuck on the half-circle progress tracker. Please tell me how to implement this. Thank you in advance :)
[This is the design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R98np.jpg)

Comment: you need a `CustomPaint` widget

Comment: I tried Custom paint but couldn't able to make it dynamic and use as a progress tracker. Can you please provide any code example related to this? @pskink

Comment: https://medium.com/@ecspike/understanding-custompaint-custompainter-and-the-canvas-3f14ce881639

Comment: you goal is to implement the half circle and just show the knob based on the credit score, it should just change based on the user credit.

Comment: Thank You Brother, Finally, I did it using CustomPainter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [CustomPainter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CustomPainter-class.html) class to create custom design like these. Check the YouTube video in the link provided. To make it work with dynamic data, you need to pass the data to the class that will extend CustomPainter.

Comment: Thank You Brother, Finally, I did it using CustomPainter.

Comment: can you please it with me @IMANULSIDDIQUE

Comment: Hi @IMANULSIDDIQUE, I didn't understand what you mean.